# Making a computer guessing game. The computer guesses the number

Tags: python, function, user-interface, module

i was able to get the assignment completed, but when I run the code on my own it does not go past a certain number of guesses. At some point the numbers will stop changing. Its like the guesses are restricted.

```
import random
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame

class GuessingGame(EasyFrame):
    """Plays a guessing game with the user."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Sets up the window,widgets, and data."""
        EasyFrame.__init__(self, title = "Guessing Game")
        self.lowerBound = 1
        self.upperBound = 100
        self.count = 0
        self.myNumber = (self.lowerBound + self.upperBound) // 2
        guess = "Is the number " + str(self.myNumber) + "?"
        self.myLabel = self.addLabel(text = guess,
                                       row = 0, column = 0,
                                       sticky = "NSEW",
                                       columnspan = 4)
        self.small = self.addButton(text = "Too small", row = 1,
                                    column = 0, command = self.goLarge)
        self.large = self.addButton(text = "Too large", row = 1,
                                        column = 1,
                                        command = self.goSmall)
        self.correct = self.addButton(text = "Correct", row = 1,
                                        column = 2,
                                        command = self.goCorrect)
        self.newButton = self.addButton(text = "New game", row = 1,
                                        column = 3,
                                        command = self.newGame)

    def goLarge(self):
        """Guess was too small, so move guess to the right of the number."""
        # Write code here
        self.count += 1
        self.lowerBound = self.myNumber + 1
        self.myNumber = (self.lowerBound + self.upperBound) // 2
        self.myLabel["text"] = "Is the number " + str(self.myNumber) + "?";
        #self.myLabel.config(text="Is it {}?".format(random.randint(self.lowerBound, self.myNumber)))
        
        
    def goSmall(self):
        """Guess was too large, so move guess to the left of the number."""
        # Write code here
        self.count += 1
        self.upperBound = self.myNumber + 1
        self.myNumber = (self.lowerBound + self.upperBound) // 2
        self.myLabel["text"] = "Is the number " + str(self.myNumber) + "?";
        #self.myLabel.config(text="Is it {}?".format(random.randint(self.myNumber, self.upperBound)))

    def goCorrect(self):
        """Guess was too correct, so announce and wait."""
        # Write code here
        self.large["state"] = "disabled"
        self.small["state"] = "disabled"
        self.correct["state"] = "disabled"
        


    def newGame(self):
        """Resets the GUI to its original state."""
        # Write code here
        self.large["state"] = "normal"
        self.small["state"] = "normal"
        self.correct["state"] = "normal"
        self.lowerBound = 1
        self.upperBound = 100
        self.count = 0
        self.myNumber = (self.lowerBound + self.upperBound) // 2
        self.myLabel["text"] = "Is the number " + str(self.myNumber) + "?"

def main():
    """Instantiate and pop up the window."""
    GuessingGame().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        main()
```

the app should be able to guess the number I am thinking of, but is not able to get there. I try to have the number guess 13 but it always freezes on number 14

Answer (score 0):

You've run into a classic off-by-one error in the binary search algorithm. In your `goLarge` method, you need to replace the line:

```py
self.lowerBound = self.myNumber + 1
```

with:

```py
self.lowerBound = self.myNumber
```